# Elasticsearch inclusive or with simple_query_string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Is there any way to use an inclusive OR with a simple query string?

With my current configuration, I have:

A | B = Every result that have A or B (A, B, AB)

I'd like to have

A | B = Every result that have A AND B then A OR B (AB, A, B)

I can't find anything in the ES's documentation. Is there a way to achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
      "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html